# Why jquery validation plugin not let the form submit in first click?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am developing portal for my client and here i am using jquery validation plugin in this project for the register form, its not let me the form submit in first click ? What issue here ? I attached jquery code here, please can help me...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#register-form').validate({
    errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
    errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
    focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
    onfocusout: false,
    /*onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,*/

    rules: {
        profile_for: {
            selectbox: true
        },
        name: "required",
        day: {
            dob: true
        },
        month: {
            dob: true
        },
        year: {
            dob: true
        },
        gender: "required",
        sub_religion: {
            selectbox: true
        },
        mother_tongue: {
            selectbox: true
        },
        caste: {
            selectbox: true
        },

        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                    url: vurl,
                    type: "post"
                 }
        },
        mobile: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            mobi: true,
            remote: {
                    url: vurl,
                    type: "post"
                 }
        },

        password: {
            required: true,
            rangelength: [6, 10]
        }

    },
    messages: {
        profile_for:  "Profile created by should not be blank",
        name: "Please specify the name",
        day: "Please provide the day of your DOB",
        month: "Please provide a month of your DOB",
        year: "Please provide a year of your DOB",
        gender: "Please select the gender",
        sub_religion: "Please specify the denomination you belong to",
        mother_tongue: "Please specify your mother tongue",
        caste: "Please specify the caste you belong to",
        email: {
            required: "Provide valid email id.  Eg.. exlmatri@gmail.com",
            email: "Provide valid email id.  Eg.. exlmatri@gmail.com",
            remote: "Email already in use!"
            },
        mobile: {
            required: "Please specify a valid mobile number",   
            number: "Please specify a valid mobile number",
            mobi: "Please specify a valid mobile number - Only 10",
            remote: "Mobile No. already in use!"
        },
        password: {
            required: "Please specify password",
            rangelength: "Please specify password with 6 to 10 characters"
        }   
    },

    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $("#register-form").find("input,select").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("error");
            $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

        });
        $("#myErrorContainer").hide();
        if(errorList.length) {
            $("#myErrorContainer").show();
            $("#myErrorContainer").html(errorList[0]['message']);
            $(errorList[0]['element']).addClass("error");
            $(errorList[0]['element']).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        }
    },  

    highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
    },

    unhighlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
    },

    success: function (label) {
        label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        label.remove();
    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {
        form.submit(); // form validation success, call ajax form submit
    }



}); 

$.validator.addMethod('dob', function (value) {
    return (value != '0');
}, "Please select date of birth");

$.validator.addMethod('selectbox', function (value, message) {
    return (value != '0');
}, "Required.");


$.validator.addMethod('mobi', function (value) {
    if($("#mobile_code").val() == '99' && value.length != 10)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}, "Required.");

});
```

Comment: you html?maybe your submit button is of type submit?make it type button or add preventDefault() to prevent autosubmit of form.

Comment: i am using the submit as follows `<button type="submit" class="btn submit pull-right" name="submit" value="register">Register</button>`

Comment: please change you change it to type button and try again

Comment: yes i tried input type button, still getting issue